# How do I make the page name variable when moving and using Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement?

Tags: flutter, dart, variables, routes, navigator

I want the name of the page to be changed to a variable so that I can use the same code once instead of writing it more than once

I tried this code but it didn't work
 `Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement( MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => e.goPage) ));`

```
List<Pages> page = [
    Pages(name: 'AnimalsSpelling', goPage: const AnimalsSpelling()),
    Pages(name: 'bodySpelling', goPage: const BodySpelling()),
  ];
 Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => e.goPage) ));
```

I tried this code but it didn't work with route
`pages.map( (e) => Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(RouteLearn(e.goPage).toString()));`